# Handling destruction of a parent node via a GraphQL mutation in Relay

Tags: relayjs, graphql

I'm curious about the "correct" way to handle a mutation where a large portion of the graph can be affected. The best example of this would be the deletion of a "parent" node that causes the deletion of a bunch of it's children. The existing mutation configs (FIELDS_CHANGED, NODE_DELETE, etc.) are sufficient for relatively simple operations, but I'm not sure the right way to handle something more complicated.

A specific example would help. Let's assume we're working on the classic Relay example app and are working with three specific types: `Ship`, `Faction`, and `User`. Let's assume `Ships` belong to a `Faction` (many to one) and `Users` have a `favorite_ships` connection (many to many). The pseudo-schema might be something like this:

```
galaxy {
  ships
  factions { ships }
  users { favorite_ships }
}
```

Alright, cool. We've got a `Faction` called "Empire" that has a bunch of ships in it's connection like "Tie Fighter", "Star Destroyer", etc. Then we have a `User` whose favorite ships include "Tie Fighter" via the `favorite_ships` connection.

All good so far. Now some punks come along and destroy the entire "Empire" `Faction` via a `DestroyFactionMutation`. The input for said mutation is fairly simple: the `Faction` id, but the impact of the mutation on the backend is large:

1. the given `Faction` node is deleted
2. all the associated `Ship` nodes are also deleted
3. all the associated `User { favorite_ship }` entries are also deleted

My question therefore is: **How do you write the mutation payload, fat query, and mutation configs to model this with Relay?**

After thinking about it a bit, I figured maybe something like this:

```
type DestroyFactionMutationPayload {
  clientMutationId: String!
  user: User
  destroyedFactionId: String
  affectedUserIds: [String]
  destroyedShipIds: [String]
}
```

Then the client would update like so:

1. add a NODE_DELETE config to remove the `Faction` node corresponding to `destroyedFactionId`, that's well documented and straight forward
2. add a NODE_DELETE config to remove the `Ship` nodes corresponding to the `destroyedShipIds` config, but using *what* for the `parentID`? Do you need to generate a NODE_DELETE for each of the `affectedUserIds`, and if so, how do you fetch those IDs so they are in the mutation props... REQUIRED_CHILDREN?
3. if #2 doesn't really work like that, maybe you can just add a FIELDS_CHANGE config that specifies that `user { favorite_ships }` can change, given the `affectedUserIds` (also probably fetched via REQUIRED_CHILDREN?)

Sorry if this is rambling and not clear; hopefully this "type" of mutation is familiar to someone who has been using Relay a bit longer. I can experiment with these options but I'd like a bit of advice on what the "best" approach for something like this would be. Thanks!